# Cursor in Input field is not vertically aligned in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Ever since I upgraded to the latest Chrome (38.0.2125.111 m), it seems like the cursor in my input fields is no longer vertically aligned. It seems to hug the top but as soon as you start typing something, it comes to the center.

I'm very sure that this used to be vertically aligned in the center in older versions of Chrome and still works appropriately in IE 10 and Firefox (33.0.2)

```
<input name="data1" id="data1" type="text" class="long-field" value="">

.long-field {
    float: left;
    width: 360px;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

I've also created a JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/cp2nctmh/

I tried to use the vertical-align css property but couldn't quite get it to work. Would appreciate your help.

Comment: I have noticed this too, but have not looked for a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `line-height: 35px` to `line-height: 1`

With `line-height: 1` you're using number values (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height). I have read several times that number values were the most appropriate value to use with line-height.

If I'm not mistaken, 1 equals the height of the font-size. So if you change the font-size the line-height also changes.

Comment: Thanks @Nuno Arruda for your fast response! And yes it does work. Can you please explain why?

Comment: Makes sense @Nuno Arruda. I saw the same explanation on css-tricks too! http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-height/  Thanks again!

Comment: Have said that... there's definitely buggy behaviour when using your original code. Maybe a bug in that Chrome version...

Answer (score 0):

Just try removing line-height property, it worked for me.

```css
.long-field {
    float: left;
    width: 360px;
    height: 35px;
    padding: 0 0 0 5px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<input name="data1" id="data1" type="text" class="long-field" value="">
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Tiago Moreira. I would rather keep the unitless line-height solution as suggested above.